# load facebook friends_list using passport-facebook in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sdk, passport.js, passport-facebook

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    authType: 'rerequest', 
    scope: ['email', 'user_friends']
}));
```

the request message is successfully sent to the logged-in user.

but there is no way to load & use that friend_list data in my nodejs application since passport-facebook profileFields does not support friend_list.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENTID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRETCODE,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
},(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);
    done(null, profile);
}));
```

is not there any way to solve this problem?

do I have to use another options like javascript sdk on client-side or something new? need some advice

Answer (score 0):

Well I would make a post request to the Facebook api using the request module and parse out the user friends.